# How do I save and load data from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have been looking for a while now for a way to do this but nothing seems to be what I am looking for, but all I want is to enter in some data into a DataGridView, save it and then if I want, later load it back up. All the tutorial seem to focus on log in data from some database or something like that when all I want is a grid where I can put things in and add a search filter tool so I can look things up. It is for a project I am doing and I was wanting a way to save and organise data efficiently like how you can as if it was a text document but in a grid with a search filter as well as the way you can send file over to someone else who has the application and read the data. Sorry if I have put it in a confusing way.

I am doing this in Visual Studio 2019 in C#

Comment: A DataGridView is for viewing data. If you want a temporary storage system you will be better off with storing in a DataTable or better still persist your data to a file (https://www.filehelpers.net/ library makes this easy)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/binding-datagrid-in-windows-form-without-database-1) as a staring point. Although such approaches seem to be outdated. (Using datatables etc) Your best bet is using classes for serializing the data to json and sending the json file